# I am installing rocM to use tensorflow in the ec2 g4ad environment, but an error ''ROCk module is NOT loaded, possibly no GPU devices'' occurs

Tags: amazon-web-services, tensorflow, amazon-ec2, amd-gpu, amd-rocm

I was setting up to run TensorFlow in g4ad environment (AMD GPU).
I followed [this guide](https://github.com/Grench6/RX580-rocM-tensorflow-ubuntu20.4-guide).

```
$ usname -a

=> Linux ip-172-31-37-18 5.4.0-1060-aws #63~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Nov 15 14:31:31 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

After entering `rocminfo` this error occurred:

```
ROCk module is NOT loaded, possibly no GPU devices
Unable to open /dev/kfd read-write: No such file or directory
ubuntu is member of video group
hsa api call failure at: /src/rocminfo/rocminfo.cc:1142
Call returned HSA_STATUS_ERROR_OUT_OF_RESOURCES: The runtime failed to allocate the necessary resources. This error may also occur when the core runtime library needs to spawn threads or create internal OS-specific events.
```